# New Google ReCAPTCHA with django-recaptcha

Tags: python, django, plugins, django-recaptcha

Is there an easy way to adapt the django-recaptcha plugin for using the new google re-captcha API? 
I already changed the template and the captcha gets displayed in the write way but the validation is not working. Has anybody an idea how I can fix this in an easy way?

Comment: have already found another plugin: django-nocaptcha-recaptcha

Answer (score 2):

Or make your own: here is mine that i made using others as a template/starting point.

```
import json
import urllib2, urllib

API_SERVER = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify"


class  RecaptchaResponse(object):
    def __init__(self, is_valid, error_code=None):
        self.is_valid = is_valid
        self.error_code = error_code

    def __unicode__(self):
        print "%s, %s" % (self.is_valid, self.error_code)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__unicode__()

    def get_error(self):
        if self.error_code and len(self.error_code):
            return self.error_code[0]


def submit(recaptcha_secret, recaptcha_response, remoteip=''):

    if not (recaptcha_secret and recaptcha_response and len(recaptcha_secret) and len(recaptcha_response) ):
        return RecaptchaResponse(is_valid=False, error_code='incorrect-captcha-sol')

    def encode_if_necessary(s):
        if isinstance(s, unicode):
            return s.encode('utf-8')
        return s

    params = urllib.urlencode({
        'secret': encode_if_necessary(recaptcha_secret),
        'response': encode_if_necessary(recaptcha_response),
        'remoteip': encode_if_necessary(remoteip)
    })

    request = urllib2.Request(
        url=API_SERVER,
        data=params,
        headers={
            "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "User-agent": "reCAPTCHA Python"
        }
    )

    httpresp = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    return_values = json.loads(httpresp.read())
    print return_values

    if return_values.get('success', False):
        return RecaptchaResponse(is_valid=True)
    else:
        return RecaptchaResponse(is_valid=False, error_code=return_values.get('error-codes', ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

Same code ported to Python 3. We are using it in production. If you preffer, [can be dowloaded from pypi/pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=display&name=norecaptcha-python3&version=1.0.0).

```
 '''
    NO-CAPTCHA VERSION: 1.0
    PYTHON VERSION:     3.x
 '''

import json
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlencode


VERIFY_SERVER = "www.google.com"


class RecaptchaResponse(object):

    def __init__(self, is_valid, error_code=None):
        self.is_valid = is_valid
        self.error_code = error_code

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Recaptcha response: %s %s" % (
            self.is_valid, self.error_code)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__repr__()


def displayhtml(site_key, language=''):
    """Gets the HTML to display for reCAPTCHA

    site_key -- The site key
    language -- The language code for the widget.
    """

    return """<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=%(LanguageCode)s" async="async" defer="defer"></script>
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="%(SiteKey)s"></div>
""" % {
        'LanguageCode': language,
        'SiteKey': site_key,
    }


def submit(response,
           secret_key,
           remote_ip,
           verify_server=VERIFY_SERVER):
    """
    Submits a reCAPTCHA request for verification. Returns RecaptchaResponse
    for the request

    response -- The value of response from the form
    secret_key -- your reCAPTCHA secret key
    remote_ip -- the user's ip address
    """

    if not(response and len(response)):
        return RecaptchaResponse(is_valid=False, error_code='incorrect-captcha-sol')

    def encode_if_necessary(s):
        if isinstance(s, str):
            return s.encode('utf-8')
        return s

    params = urlencode({
        'secret': encode_if_necessary(secret_key),
        'remoteip': encode_if_necessary(remote_ip),
        'response': encode_if_necessary(response),
    })

    params = params.encode('utf-8')

    request = Request(
        url="https://%s/recaptcha/api/siteverify" % verify_server,
        data=params,
        headers={
            "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "User-agent": "reCAPTCHA Python"
        }
    )
    httpresp = urlopen(request)

    return_values = json.loads(httpresp.read().decode('utf-8'))
    httpresp.close()

    return_code = return_values['success']

    if return_code:
        return RecaptchaResponse(is_valid=True)
    else:
        return RecaptchaResponse(is_valid=False, error_code=return_values['error-codes'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I know your question is old, but Nowadays, you just have to write in settings.py:

```
NOCAPTCHA = True
```

And that's it.